# Docker on RaspBerryPi: "pyinit_main: can't initialize time" when running "RUN pip install pyserial" from DOCKERFILE

Tags: python, docker, pip

I have a RaspberryPi (Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3, ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l), 32 bit). The system thereon is a Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) with the lastest apt update/apt-get upgrade.

I try to run the following DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine


# install required libs to exercise code 
RUN pip install pyserial

# the actual python code
ADD myFile.py
CMD [ "python", "./myFile.py"]
```

When building the Dockerfile (`docker build -t cryo-logger .`) I get the following error when `RUN pip install pyserial` is called:

```
Fatal Python error: pyinit_main: can't initialize time
Python runtime state: core initialized PermissionError:
[Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Current thread 0x76fb7390 (most recent call first): <no Python frame>
```

I already tried things suggested in other threads:

- `sudo apt search libseccomp` returns:

  golang-github-seccomp-libseccomp-golang-dev/oldoldstable 0.0~git20150813.0.1b506fc-2+deb9u1 all
  golang bindings for libseccomp

  libseccomp-dev/oldoldstable 2.3.1-2.1+deb9u1 armhf
  high level interface to Linux seccomp filter (development files)

  libseccomp2/oldoldstable,now 2.3.1-2.1+deb9u1 armhf  [installiert]
  high level interface to Linux seccomp filter

  seccomp/oldoldstable 2.3.1-2.1+deb9u1 armhf
  helper tools for high level interface to Linux seccomp filter
- Tried `docker build ... --platform ...arm7...`

Comment: Permission error, does your python file have execute permissions? You may want to change the file permissions before running is with `./` like `./myFile.py`.

Comment: do you mean the `RUN pip install pyserial --privileged`? I tried this as well

Comment: The problem does not occur at `CMD [...]` but at `RUN pip install pyserial`

Comment: Have the same problem. Is it solved?

Comment: @Predicate: Nope, unfortunately not

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem on a Raspberry Pi 4.  I ended up finding that I needed a newer version of libseccomp2.  This can be done by performing the following:

```
# Get signing keys to verify the new packages, otherwise they will not install
rpi ~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 04EE7237B7D453EC 648ACFD622F3D138

# Add the Buster backport repository to apt sources.list
rpi ~$ echo 'deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-backports.list

rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt install libseccomp2 -t buster-backports
```

You should also check your version of Docker.  Versions prior to 19.04 can also cause this issue.  I'm running Docker v25.0.2 which is working fine.

For more information check out: https://blog.samcater.com/fix-workaround-rpi4-docker-libseccomp2-docker-20/